# How was 'fissiparus' mistakenly analogized with 'vīviparus'?

Tags: etymology, word-comparison

Is [the Wiktionary entry on *fissiparous*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fissiparous) below correct? Why's the analogy "mistaken"? The compounding makes sense to me?

> #### Etymology
>
> An adaptation of the [New Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Latin) *[fissiparus](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=fissiparus&action=edit&redlink=1)*, from *[fissus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fissus#Latin)* (“split”, “cleft”) + *[pariō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pario#Latin)* (“I bring forth”) by mistaken analogy with *[vīviparus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viviparus#Latin)*.

Answer (score 3):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fissiparous) has the fuller picture:

> When it first entered English in the 19th century, "fissiparous" was concerned with reproduction. In biology, a fissiparous organism is one that produces new individuals by fission; that is, by dividing into separate parts, each of which becomes a unique organism. (Most strains of bacteria do this.) Fissiparous derives from Latin fissus, the past participle of "findere" ("to split"), and parere, meaning "to give birth to or "to produce." Other "parere" offspring refer to other forms of reproduction, including "oviparous" ("producing eggs that hatch outside the body") and "viviparous" ("producing living young instead of eggs"). By the end of the 19th century "fissiparous" had acquired a figurative meaning, describing something that breaks into parts or causes something else to break into parts.

Answer (score 2):

*Viviparus* comes from *vivus* ("alive") and *parere* ("to give birth"), and it makes sense that it means something that gives birth to living offspring.

As Wiktionary tells, *fissus* means "split".
Therefore *fissiparus* should refer to something that gives birth to split offspring.
The word *fissiparus* or the English variant appears to mean something that has a tendency to split.
The component *fissi-* makes sense, but *-parus* does not.
No giving birth is involved.

Perhaps the *-parus* of *viviparus* was analyzed as "related", and then "related to being alive" was converted to "related to splitting".
But this analogy is indeed mistaken, as *-parus* has a much more specific meaning than just "related".

An obvious follow-up question presents itself:
What would then be a good Latin word with a meaning suitable for what *fissiparus* is used for?
I suggest taking that to a separate question if you are interested.

Comment: There is some analogy here with “iatrogenic disease”, which literally means “disease that gives rise to doctors”. It seems that scientific English is equally happy when the noun (or adjective) in the compound is the subject or the object of the verb.

Comment: I would tend to thing that the mistake in the analogy lies not so much in the choice of -parous, since fissiparous does in fact have to do with birth/reproduction ('producing new individuals by fission,' according to my dictionary); rather, it lies in the fact that in the word viviparous, the first root has a direct object relationship with the second, whereas in fissiparous, it stands in the relationship of instrument/means. As you note, though, to be a proper analogy with viviparous, fissiparous should mean 'producing split offspring.'

Comment: Which is not to say that fissiparous is, per se, an improper word formation. Having the first root in a compound express the instrument/means of the second, verbal root, is perfectly valid and common. It's just that, as a word that's supposed to have been formed by analogy with viviparous, it doesn't quite work.